# Tomboy: Close Notes Using shortcut Key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, tomboy

In tomboy 1.15 I'm looking for keyboard shortcuts to open and close multiple notes at once.

Opening's easy enough: select the notes in the "Search All Notes" window and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>.

Is there a shortcut to close all selected notes?